# Show selected category

Tags: laravel

How can i show in my edit.blade.php the selected category of my product. you can only choose 1 category so is not many to many relation.

Product model :

```
   public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

Category model :

```
  public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

Db products:
[image]

```html
<div class="form-group my-2">
 <label for="category">Choose Category  :</label>
 <select name="category_id" class="form-control custom-select">
  @foreach($categories as $category)
   <option value="{{$category->id}}" @if($product->category->contains($category->id)) selected @endif>{{$category->name}}</option>
  @endforeach
 </select>
</div>
```

I keep getting errors like :
Call to undefined method App\Models\Category::contains()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel version < 9

```
<option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ ($product->category_id == $category->id) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>
```

Larvel version > 9

```
<option value="{{ $category->id }}" @selected($product->category_id == $category->id)>{{ $category->name }}</option>
```

> Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#checked-and-selected

Answer (score 0):

Your product `belongsTo` category:

```
<option value="{{$category->id}}" @if($product->category_id == $category->id) selected @endif>{{$category->name}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
 <option value="{{$category->id}}" {{($product->category_id == $category->id) ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$category->name}}</option>
```